# Moving the plot regrading to the offset

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot, mplcursors

Dears,

I wrote this code to calculate the distance between two mouse clicks on the plot. Now I am trying to move the plot to the left or to the right with regards to the calculated offset so that the two plots are exactly match. any idea how to achieve that? I tried to add and subtract normally but it did not work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import mplcursors
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

class DistancePlot:
    def __init__(self):
        
        ROOT = tk.Tk()
        ROOT.withdraw()
        ROOT.geometry("500x200")
        #my_frame = Frame(ROOT)
        #my_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        USER_INP = (simpledialog.askinteger(title="Plot dialig", 
                                  prompt="Enter the number of the plots "))
        
        if USER_INP is not None: 
            def f(x):
                return np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))
            self.x = np.linspace(1, 10)
            self.fig, self.ax= plt.subplots()
            for i in range(USER_INP):
                plt.plot(self.x, f(self.x))

       
            self.ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
            self.ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')

            self.d1 = (0.0, 0.0)
            self.d2 = (0.0, 0.0)

            self.first_click = True

            self.cursor=Cursor(self.ax, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color='black', linewidth=1.0)

            self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick)

            mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
            plt.show()
            
        else: 
            def quit(self):
                self.ROOT.destroy()
        
    def onclick(self, event):
        z1, r1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
        print(z1, r1)

        if self.first_click:
            self.first_click = False
            self.d1 = (z1, r1)
        else:
            self.first_click = True
            self.d2 = (z1, r1)
            distance = sqrt((((self.d1[0]) - (self.d2[0])) ** 2) + (((self.d1[1]) - (self.d2[1])) ** 2))
            print("The shift between ", self.d1, "and", self.d2, "is", distance)
    
            
dp = DistancePlot()
```

the answer in the comment was helpful but this is not exactly what I want, I tried to use the same logic to get to my solution but it didn't work and I will share it with you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import mplcursors
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import simpledialog

class DistancePlot:
    def __init__(self):
        ROOT = tk.Tk()
        ROOT.withdraw()
        ROOT.geometry("500x200")
#        USER_INP = 1
        
        #random sine wave
        x = np.linspace(1, 10)
        def f(x):
            return np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x)) 
        #fixed sine wave 
        time= np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
        amplitude   = np.sin(time)
        
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ax.plot(x, f(x))
        self.ax.plot(time, amplitude)
        self.ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
        self.d1 = np.zeros(2)
        self.d2 = np.zeros(2)

        self.first_click = True
        self.cursor = Cursor(self.ax, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color='black', linewidth=1)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick)
        mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
        plt.show()
            

    def onclick(self, event):
        z1, r1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
        print(z1, r1)
        if self.first_click:
            self.first_click = False
            self.d1 = np.array((z1, r1))
        else:
            self.first_click = True
            self.d2 = np.array((z1, r1))
            #distance = sqrt((((self.d1[0]) - (self.d2[0])) ** 2) + (((self.d1[1]) - (self.d2[1])) ** 2))
            #print("The distance between ", self.d1, "and", self.d2, "is", distance)
            delta = self.d2 - self.d1
            print("The delta between ", self.d1, "and", self.d2, "is", delta)
            if (abs(self.d2[0]) > abs(self.d1[0])).all():
                self.ax.lines[0].set_data(self.ax.lines[0].get_data() - delta.reshape(2,1))
                self.ax.relim()
                self.ax.autoscale_view()
                plt.draw()
                
            else: 
                self.ax.lines[0].set_data(self.ax.lines[0].get_data() + delta.reshape(2,1))
                self.ax.relim()
                self.ax.autoscale_view()
                plt.draw()

dp = DistancePlot()
```

what I want is use a reference graph and match it with another graph, if the graph I am adding is leading I want it to be subtracted and if it lagging I want it to move forward so adding it to the delta.

Comment: Can you explain a bit deeper what you mean by *"if the graph I am adding is leading I want it to be subtracted and if it is lagging I want it to move forward so adding it to the delta"*?  Maybe by "subtracted" you mean cut off a part?  By "move forward", maybe you mean "cut off a part of the reference graph"?  Maybe you could add a photoshopped image to clarify both cases?

Comment: No actually it is not cutting, I just mean to move the graph right or left with regards to the lead and lag concept. I will explain in another word, Imagine you have a reference curve that you use to match any other curve with it, so the reference graph is not moving and it is fixed, however I want to move any the other graph either to the left or right (based on its current location) in order to match the reference graph. it actually similar to what you have did before but it is not exactly what I need since both curves change their locations and there is no graph refer to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach, moving the first curve over the given distance. Numpy arrays are used to simplify the loops. `relim()` and `autoscale_view()` recalculate the x and y limits to fit everything again inside a margin (this step can be skipped if the expected displacement is small).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import mplcursors
from math import sqrt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

class DistancePlot:
    def __init__(self):
        ROOT = tk.Tk()
        ROOT.withdraw()
        ROOT.geometry("500x200")
        USER_INP = 2
        # USER_INP = (simpledialog.askinteger(title="Plot dialig", prompt="Enter the number of the plots "))
        if USER_INP is not None:
            def f(x):
                return np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))

            self.x = np.linspace(1, 10)
            self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
            for i in range(USER_INP):
                self.ax.plot(self.x, f(self.x))
            self.ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
            self.ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
            self.d1 = np.zeros(2)
            self.d2 = np.zeros(2)

            self.first_click = True
            self.cursor = Cursor(self.ax, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color='black', linewidth=1)
            self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick)
            mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
            plt.show()
        else:
            def quit(self):
                self.ROOT.destroy()

    def onclick(self, event):
        z1, r1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
        if self.first_click:
            self.first_click = False
            self.d1 = np.array((z1, r1))
        else:
            self.first_click = True
            self.d2 = np.array((z1, r1))
            distance = sqrt((((self.d1[0]) - (self.d2[0])) ** 2) + (((self.d1[1]) - (self.d2[1])) ** 2))
            delta = self.d2 - self.d1
            self.ax.lines[0].set_data(self.ax.lines[0].get_data() + delta.reshape(2,1))
            self.ax.relim()
            self.ax.autoscale_view()
            plt.draw()

dp = DistancePlot()
```

If you only want to move left-right, you can use `set_xdata` to only change the x-positions. The following example code moves the second curve with the given displacement. If you want to move to the left, the second click should be to the left of the first.

```py
    def onclick(self, event):
        z1, r1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
        if self.first_click:
            self.first_click = False
            self.d1 = np.array((z1, r1))
        else:
            self.first_click = True
            self.d2 = np.array((z1, r1))
            delta_x = self.d1[0] - self.d2[0]
            self.ax.lines[1].set_xdata(self.ax.lines[1].get_xdata() + delta_x)
            self.ax.relim()
            self.ax.autoscale_view()
            plt.draw()
```

Comment: your answer is really helpful, However, I tried to use your logic to implement my idea but it didn't work. Could you please have a look to my edited comment?